# Copying files over chained SSH connection

Tags: ssh, sftp, scp

I am using a remote server and want to copy files from the server.
When using the server, I need to log in with 2 steps.
ssh `username@A`
after loging into server A, I need to log in again.
`ssh username@B`. 
So I am in server B now. (by `uname -a`)
Is there anyway to download files in server B to local computer?
I tried sftp and scp, but I don't know how to specify the server name. 
Both of username@A and username@B have been tested, which don't work.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/66327/copying-a-file-2-connections-away/66332#66332

Answer (score 5):

First fire up an SSH tunnel from your local machine to Server B, through A:

```
$ ssh user@serverA -L2222:serverB:22
```

Then from another terminal, scp directly to/from B:

```
$ scp -P 2222 /path/to/file user@localhost:/path/to/destination
```

Note that due to port tunnelling, `user@localhost` is actually `user@serverB`, so make sure to use the appropriate username for that remote server.